# How to access data from different time levels

Tags: pine-script

In a pine script I would like to color the background of the chart at all time levels based on indicators on the daily level. For example: Green background in the 1 hour and 4 hour chart if the moving average (SMA) on daily basis is rising.

Any idea how I can best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
study("My Script")
ma = sma(close, 14)
raising = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ma > ma[1])
bgcolor(raising ? color.green : color.red, transp = 70)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Much appreciated.